# Filling a table with JSON data

Tags: json, angular

I am taking mmy first steps in Angular and was about to try populating a table with data stored in a JSON file. Facing a bit of an odd/unexpected situation there as the table doesn't look exactly how I expected it to look. First things first.

Table code:

```
  <table class="table  table-sm table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Transfers</th>
      <th>Tools</th>
    </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor = "let data of linksArray">
        <td>{{ data.Transfers}}</td>
        <td>{{ data.Tools}}</td>
       
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

What I would like to achieve is that the columns Transfers and Tools get filled with data that uses the corresponding keywords in my JSON file. And here it is

```
[{"Type":"Transfers","Name":"1","Hyperlink":"#"}, {"Type":"Transfers","Name":"2","Hyperlink":"#"}, 
 {"Type":"Tools","Name":"1","Hyperlink":"#"}, {"Type":"Tools","Name":"2","Hyperlink":"#"}]
```

The array gets loaded by using this in my .ts file

```
 this.http.get('../../assets/templatefiles/links.json').subscribe(data => {this.linksArray = data as 
any [];
  console.log(this.linksArray);
},
  (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    console.log (err.message);
  
}
);
```

So far all looks good, I see the array popping up in console, but then look at the table and am confused

[image]

I would have expected the entries in the 2nd column to start in the first cell. Instead they start in the 3rd? What am I missing here? Been marveling for quite a while now :)

Comment: I'd recommend using https://stackblitz.com/ to create Angular examples. People can then look at, and possibly fix, your code directly

Comment: Maybe this tutorial will give you some information to create your own reusable table component: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLREvIK3N7Ga5XiIab1aelyvqfOZwMpyj6, but I'm use Indonesian language. For opensource code, you can look at:https://github.com/12bedeveloper/ngid-table

Answer (score 0):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hvcyfq

To get this

```
Transfers   Tools
1   10
2   20
```

You want code roughly like this

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
  <table class="table  table-sm table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Transfers</th>
      <th>Tools</th>
    </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of linksArray">
        <td>{{data.Transfers.Name}}</td>
        <td>{{data.Tools.Name}}</td>       
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

And, this is the main bit, json roughly like this

```
 linksArray = [
   {
      Transfers: {
         Name:"1",
         Hyperlink:"#"
      },
      Tools: {
         Name:"10",
         Hyperlink:"#"
      }
   },
   {
      Transfers: {
         Name:"2",
         Hyperlink:"#"
      },
      Tools: {
         Name:"20",
         Hyperlink:"#"
      }
   },
```

Your existing json looks like this, where the '{' represents one row

```
[
   {
      "Type":"Transfers",
      "Name":"1",
      "Hyperlink":"#"
   },
   {
      "Type":"Transfers",
      "Name":"2",
      "Hyperlink":"#"
   },
   {
      "Type":"Tools",
      "Name":"1",
      "Hyperlink":"#"
   },
   {
      "Type":"Tools",
      "Name":"2",
      "Hyperlink":"#"
   }
]
```